# Handle escaping for \r\n in spark csv

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-redshift

My source file is an unload from amazon redshift database.I extracted the data using UNLOAD command.My data has a column with freeform text with windows newline (\r\n) characters and it will have quote (") characters as well.

But redshift gives option only to ADDQUOTES but not provide a way to chose what that quote character can be and same is the case with ESCAPE.Their implementation adds escape character(\) before all of the below characters.

- Linefeed: \n
- Carriage return: \r
- The delimiter character specified for the unloaded data. The escape
  character: \
- A quote character: " or ' (if both ESCAPE and ADDQUOTES are specified
  in the UNLOAD command).

More info(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html)

Because of this, the unloaded data has escape characters before each of the the windows newline characters like "\\r\\n".

When I try to read this file through spark.read.csv() with escape='\\' option, it is not removing the escape(\) character that was added in front of \r and \n.

I understand that spark will consider escaping only when the chosen quote character comes as part of the quoted data string.

I can remove that after being read into a dataframe.But is there anyway to remove the additional escape(\) characters in the data while reading into the dataframe?

Appreciate your help!

**Sample records(with escape characters before the \r\n):**

```
1,"this is \^M\
 line1"
2,"this is \^M\
 li\"ne2"
3,"this is \^M\
 line3"
```

This is how the redshift unload file inserts escape characters.Infront of quote characters if it comes as part of the data and before each \r and \n respectively.

When I read this file into a dataframe,spark correctly removes the escape characters before \n and quote(") but retains that infront of \r.

```
>>> df2 = spark.read.csv("file:///tmp/sample_modified.csv",header=False,quote='"',sep=',',escape='\\',multiLine=True,inferSchema=False)
>>> df2.show(5,False)
+---+-------------------+
|_c0|_c1                |
+---+-------------------+
\1  |this is \
 line1 |
\2  |this is \
 li"ne2|
\3  |this is \
 line3 |
+---+-------------------+
```

**expected result(without escape character"\"):**

```
+---+----------------+
|_c0|_c1             |
+---+----------------+
|1  |this is 
 line1|
|2  |this is 
li"ne2|
|3  |this is 
line3 |
+---+----------------+
```

**PS** - Since this appears to be a limitation, I have opened a JIRA issue in Apache Spark project.(https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26786)

Comment: how are the records separated - newlines?

Comment: records are separated by unix newline (\n) character

Comment: try with triple quotes ````"""\\"""````

Comment: can you paste sample records ...

Comment: @stack0114106 I have added the sample records. ^M is the windows (\r) representation followed by the linebreak.

Comment: this is still a bug in spark module.. someone mentioned ````option("wholeFile", "true")```` would solve it.. but it didn't work

Comment: but I can suggest a workaround.. do you want to proceed?

Comment: Thanks @stack0114106. We can successfully parse the file with multiLine=True option but the problem that I am running into is the escape characters coming before windows \r\n characters. My understanding is that spark's csv module doesn't escape any newline characters in a quoted data string/column. Since my incoming data file writes the escape characters before the \r\n, I was wondering if I can do something about this while reading the file itself into a dataframe

Comment: Sure, please share me the solution.

Comment: yes.. you are right, with multiLine=true it works.. I'm pasting the code in answer..just check out.. and we can fine tune it

Comment: does that solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

This is how the file looks in cygwin

```
$ cat -vT vishsnu.csv
"ID","Desc"
1001,"this ^M
 is line1"
1002,"this ^M
 is line2"
1003,"this ^M
 is line3"
$
```

Spark code

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv")
            .option("wholeFile", "true")
  .option("multiLine","true")
            .option("inferSchema","true")
            .option("header","true")
           // .option("escape","""\""")  this is commented
            .load("in_201901/vishsnu.csv")

df.show(false)
df.select("desc").show(false)
println("Count of dataframe records " + df.count)
```

Results:

```
+----+---------------+
|ID  |Desc           |
+----+---------------+
|1001|this 
 is line1|
|1002|this 
 is line2|
|1003|this 
 is line3|
+----+---------------+

+---------------+
|desc           |
+---------------+
|this 
 is line1|
|this 
 is line2|
|this 
 is line3|
+---------------+

Count of dataframe records 3
```

The regex_replace functions didn't help to remove the \r\n characters.
But the translate function did. See below

```
  df.withColumn("desc2",translate(translate('desc,"\r",""),"\n", "")).select('id,'desc2).show(false)
```

Results

```
+----+--------------+
|id  |desc2         |
+----+--------------+
|1001|this  is line1|
|1002|this  is line2|
|1003|this  is line3|
+----+--------------+
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help here. I have added more information to my question to better explain my request.From what I could understand , there isn't way to make the spark csv reader to remove the escape characters infront of newline(\r\n) while reading into the dataframe. After the dataframe is created we can apply the transformations to remove the additional escape characters.

Comment: yes.. you are right.. I also tested in many ways .. using regexp_replace also.. didn't go well.. the translate function worked.. give a try

Comment: I have added a new feature request in spark jira board.(https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26786)

Comment: @vishnu.. that's great. you have compared with python native csv solution in the jira.. lets hope that it gets fixed in upcoming release..

Comment: @vishnu.. also add a PS in your question that this is an existing issue and you have opened a jira.. and share the link..

Comment: Sure, I have added the suggested information. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to do the same in Spark Sql? I am passing `sqlStringFromDB = """select myCol, translate(translate(myCol,"\r",""),"\n", "") as new_column from myTable"""`but it doesn't help.

Comment: By the way I tried this - in df.show(false) it shows without any carriage returns but when I open the file written on windows machine in notepad++, it still shows CRLF. Am I missing something? `val dfToWrite = df.withColumn("new_column", translate(translate('myCol, "\r", ""), "\n", "")).select('myCol, 'new_column)`

Answer (score 0):

Below code works fine.

```
df=df2.select(*(regexp_replace(col(c),"\\\\\r\\\\\n","\r\n").alias(c) for c in df2.columns))

>>> df.show()
+---+-----------------+
|_c0|              _c1|
+---+-----------------+
|  1| this is line1   |
|  2| this is li"ne2  |
|  3| this is li\ne3  |
+---+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Valan.I will have to use something like what you have suggested until this is addressed at Spark.